# MV refresh without deleting the data

Tags: oracle

Experts,

I need help to create a Materialized view in Oracle that doesn't delete the data from MV on delete from the base table.

My base table:

```
1) create table one11 (aa INT, bb INT, cc varchar2(10));
2) alter table one11 add primary key(aa);
3) insert into one11 values(1,1,'AA');
4) insert into one11 values(2,1,'BB');
5) insert into one11 values(3,1,'CC');

6)CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON ONE11 
WITH PRIMARY KEY, SEQUENCE, ROWID(BB, CC) 
INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

7)CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW one11_mv
REFRESH FAST
START WITH (SYSDATE) NEXT (SYSDATE + interval '1' minute)  AS
select * from one11;

8)select * from one11_mv; --After 1 min
AA  BB  CC
1   1   AA
2   1   BB
3   1   CC

9) delete from one11 where aa= 3; --After 1 min
AA  BB  CC
1   1   AA
2   1   BB

----
The expected result from MV after delete statement
AA  BB  CC
1   1   AA
2   1   BB
3   1   CC

TIA
```

Comment: I wonder if this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where you're asking about your solution instead of your problem. Do you need to have an MV and a table, or are you just looking for a soft-delete option? If you just want a soft delete, Chris's answer has some good suggestions. You can also use Oracle's built in [in-database archiving](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/in-database-archiving-12cr1). Or perhaps you can use a view with an instead-of trigger that ignores or transforms deletes.

Answer (score 1):

No. To refresh the data in an MV, you've got two options:

- Complete refresh: re-run the query in the MV
- Fast refresh: apply all the changes in the MV log

Either way you're going to lose deleted rows. So if you want to delete rows from the base table, but keep them in the MV you'll have to change tack.

Ways you could do this include:

- Roll your own MV: copy everything to another table on insert/update
- Change to soft deletes: add an `is_deleted` flag to the table and change all `deletes` to be `updates` that set this flag. The MV can then include these "deleted" rows, while all other application code hides them

Comment: I believe, I have got the solution here. I Just need to write some script that will insert the newly added data in the base table into a custom table on the daily basis.

Thanks Chris and Jon